# accessing vagrant homestead projects via URL on IE11 from guest VM running windows 10 (senglin/win-10-enterprise-vs2015community)

Tags: vagrant, virtual-machine, virtualbox, homestead

I have vagrant homestead and the vagrant box with Windows 10 (senglin/win-10-enterprise-vs2015community).

I have been using vagrant homestead to build projects locally on my Mac for a while but now need access to IE11 for testing - so I installed the vagrant box with Windows 10.

On my host machine I had previously setup the hosts file to point to the homestead machine IP like this:

```
192.168.10.10   homestead.projects.com
```

With this I can access my projects via url from any browser on my host.

Now, I need the new Windows 10 VM to access those projects from homestead on browsers like IE11 from within the VM - can someone tell me how to achieve this?

Thank you